# How to change object color in sparx based on GUID

Tags: python, perl, enterprise-architect

I can't get my head around it :-)
How can I change the colour (background colour) of an object (BPMN Activity) in Sparx with a program?

I have the GUID, I can select the object, just con't figure it out how to change the colour?

Let's say I have an object with GUID {E595409F-CFED-4334-8DA3-F13D8A81A534} and I want the background colour to be red.

What would be the code (in Perl, Python or visual basic, any would do). Not inside Sparx scripting.

Here is the code (python)

```
import win32com.client

eaApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App")

#print the connection string
eaRep = eaApp.Repository
print('Connection string: ', eaRep.ConnectionString)

#select the activity based on GUID
guid = '{E595409F-CFED-4334-8DA3-F13D8A81A534}'
activity = eaRep.GetElementByGUID(guid)
print('Activity: ', activity.Name)

#Change the backgroud color to red

activity.Style = '''BCol=255;'''
activity.Update
```

but the last 2 lines are wrong as those are the once i do not know how to

Comment: Please post the code you have already and where you are stuck. You can't expect SO to solve the whole problem for you.

Comment: thx. code added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style on the element is the default appearance for this element whenever used on a diagram.

On each diagram this can be overridden. These settings are stored in `EA.DiagramObject`.

Presuming you are trying to change the default appearance you should use `EA.Element.SetAppearance(long Scope, long Item, long Value)`.

The [help file](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/element2.html) says following about that:

> Void
>
> Notes: Sets the visual appearance of the element.
>
> Parameters:
>
> •Scope: Long - Scope of appearance set to modify  
> 1  - Base
> (Default appearance across entire model) 
>  To set appearance for the
> element (diagram object) in a selected diagram only, see Setting The
> Style in the DiagramObject Class topic
>  •Item: Long - Appearance
> feature to modify 
>  0 - Background color 
>  1 - Font Color 
>  2 - Border
> Color
>   3 - Border Width 
> •Value: Long - Value to set appearance to

Comment: thank you Geert. Will take a look in that direction.

Comment: FWIW: The `diagramObject` has `objectStyle` noted in the `BCOL=x;` format in case you want to set the color individually per diagram.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, got it working. Not the best one, still got few things to tweak but it is working. I have put the code into the question

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it working. Here is the code which is working now.

```
import win32com.client
#Declare what
DiagramGUID = '{9262BA28-AE78-45ce-A060-FEC95DE4301E}'
ObjectGUI = '{6B80AB10-0104-4d42-B5BF-2EDC4EA053CC}'
ObjectColor = '''255'''

#connect to EA
eaApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App")
#get the repository
Repository = eaApp.Repository
print('Connection string: ', Repository.ConnectionString, '\n')
#get diagram using GUID
dia = Repository.GetDiagramByGUID(DiagramGUID)
print('Diagram name selected: ', dia.Name)

#Get the activity ID based on GUID
activity = Repository.GetElementByGUID(ObjectGUI)
ElementID = activity.ElementID

#get the fist object in the diagram
dia_obj = dia.DiagramObjects.GetAt(0)

#start from 0
i = 0
#now find the right diagram object based on ID
while (dia_obj.ElementID != ElementID):
    i = i+1
    print('i is ', i)
    print('comparing ', dia_obj.ElementID, ' with ', ElementID)
    dia_obj = dia.DiagramObjects.GetAt(i)
#change the style and update diagram object
dia_obj.SetStyleEx('''BCol''',ObjectColor)
dia_obj.Update()
```

There would be an error (which I need to take care of if the proper object will not be found. If there is a better way to do what I need to do please let me know.

Comment: You know that this will change the diagram representations of your element. Means: if you add it as link to a diagram it will have the default appearance. Using the `setAppearance` would have a global effect.

Comment: I don't want to change it globally. That is why I'm not using `setApperance` as the plan is to alter one diagram (kind of dashboard) based on a file. So just on one diagram.

Comment: Ah, ok. That was not clear from your question. (And then Geert's answer would not be the correct one. So we leave it as it is.)